# Matching unordered values in R

Tags: r, matching, unordered

I'm working with a dataset with two columns that look something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Row1 = c("1, 2", "2, 6, 4", "3, 1", "2, 1, 4", "3"),
  Row2 = c("2, 5", "2, 6", "1, 3", "1, 4, 2", "3, 2")
)
```

| Row1 | Row2 |
| --- | --- |
| "1, 2" | "2, 5" |
| "2, 6, 4" | "2, 6" |
| "3, 1" | "1, 3" |
| "2, 1, 4" | "1, 4, 2" |
| "3 | "3, 2" |

I want to run a script that allows me to identify whether Row2 matches Row1. The need to have the same exact values, but they don't need to be in the same order. So given the above, I'd want a result that tells me the following:

| Row1 | Row2 | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "1, 2" | "2, 5" | FALSE |
| "2, 6, 4" | "2, 6" | FALSE |
| "3, 1" | "1, 3" | TRUE |
| "2, 1, 4" | "1, 4, 2" | TRUE |
| "3" | "3, 2" | FALSE |

I've tried using match() and compare() and haven't found success with either. Match() produces TRUE as long as all the elements of Row1 are found in Row2, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I need to produce TRUE *only* when Row2 has the same exact numbers as Row1 and *only* those numbers, irrespective of order. On the other hand, Compare() produces an error if I try to create a new column to identify matches. This is what I enter:

```
df$match <- compareIgnoreOrder(df$row1, df$row2)
```

I've also tried this way:

```
df$match <- compare(df$row1, df$row2, ignoreAll = TRUE)
```

Both methods yield the following error: "Input must be a vector, not a  object." And at this point I'm stuck. I've searched high and low but can't find any solutions. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `2,6,4` for example just a string - `"2,6,4"` or are these vectors in each cell like `c(2,6,4)` ?

Comment: And what about the instance of comparing `c(1,3)` with `c(1,1,3)` - what would you like the result to be?

Comment: Regarding your first question, each cell is a vector containing a series of different values separated by commas. Regarding your second question, in the instance of c(1,3) and c(1,1,3), I would like the result to show this as true match. (However, in my data this won't be an issue as I've already taken out duplicates.)

Comment: And sorry just to clarify, the above should say "each cell *contains* a series..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing sets, so a set operation like `?setequal` makes sense to me:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Row1 = c("1, 2", "2, 6, 4", "3, 1", "2, 1, 4", "3"),
  Row2 = c("2, 5", "2, 6", "1, 3", "1, 4, 2", "3, 2")
)

do.call(mapply, c(setequal, unname(lapply(df, strsplit, split=",\\s+"))))
##[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or in a potentially less confusing form but one extra line:

```
spl <- lapply(df, strsplit, split=",\\s+")
mapply(setequal, spl[[1]], spl[[2]])
##[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when I put in my data. I've tried running several solutions such as making sure my data is interpreted as a double, making sure it runs as a list, etc., but nothing seems to work. What I don't understand is that it works fine when I plug in the code you put above. But if I run my own data through it, it doesn't. This makes me think I need to fix something with how the data itself is being interpreted, but I don't know what that could be.

Comment: @Bridget - can you post `dput(head(df$row1))` so I know exactly the structure of your column. It's probably a simple fix.

Comment: sure, copy-pasting below

Comment: > dput(head(full_data$correct_response_id))
c("2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5")
> dput(head(full_data$coder_response_id))
c("2, 5", "5, 2", "2, 5", "2, 5, 4", "5, 6, 2, 1", "5, 2")

Comment: @Bridget - see updated answer which should match your format now. Since each value is just a string, they need to be `strsplit` so the sets can be compared.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Match = length(intersect(Row1,Row2)) == length(union(Row1,Row2)))
```

Output:

```
  Row1      Row2      Match
  <list>    <list>    <lgl>
1 <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> FALSE
2 <dbl [3]> <dbl [2]> FALSE
3 <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> TRUE 
4 <dbl [3]> <dbl [3]> TRUE 
5 <dbl [1]> <dbl [2]> FALSE
```

Input:

```
data <- tibble(
  Row1 = list(c(1,2), c(2,6,4), c(3,1), c(2,1,4), c(3)),
  Row2 = list(c(2,5), c(2,6), c(1,3), c(1,4,2), c(3,2))
)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with this as with the solution suggested above. When I input the code you have here, it works fine. But when I try to put in my data, it doesn't work properly. I'm honestly baffled.

Comment: @Bridget, if you use `dput(df)`, or maybe `dput(head(df,20))` and paste the output in your question, we might be able to see the difference between your data, and the input data that I have used here

Comment: sure, copy-pasting below

Comment: > dput(head(full_data$correct_response_id))
c("2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5", "2, 5")
> dput(head(full_data$coder_response_id))
c("2, 5", "5, 2", "2, 5", "2, 5, 4", "5, 6, 2, 1", "5, 2")